# Make Graphstream render only what changed

Tags: java, rendering, graphstream

I created a graph that represents the road map of a certain region using `Graphstream`.

[image: Road map]

Now I want to make it look like the blue node is moving on the graph and for that I'm showing the graph on another thread and, every second, I color a different node blue, like so:

```java
public void drawGraph(List<MyCustomNodeClass> nodes, List<MyCustomEdgeClass> edges){
    Graph graph = new MultiGraph("main graph");
    Viewer viewer = new Viewer(graph, Viewer.ThreadingModel.GRAPH_IN_ANOTHER_THREAD);
    ViewerPipe pipeIn = viewer.newViewerPipe();
    viewer.addView("view1", new J2DGraphRenderer());

    pipeIn.addAttributeSink(graph);
    pipeIn.pump();

    nodes.forEach(node-> graph.addNode(node.getId()));

    edges.forEach(edge-> graph.getEdge(edge.getId(), edge.getSrc(), edge.getDest()));

    Node node = graph.getNode("start");

    while(true){
        pipeIn.pump();

        sleep(100);

        node.setAttribute("ui.style", "z-index: 1; size: 3px; fill-color: black;");

        node = node = node.getNeighborNodeIterator().next();;

        node.setAttribute("ui.style", "z-index: 2; size: 10px; fill-color: blue;");
    }
}
```

```java
private void sleep(long seconds ) {
    try { Thread.sleep( seconds ) ; }
    catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

As the title suggest, my problem is that the graph is huge (15997 edges, 9084 nodes), and it makes it such that the time it takes `GraphStream` to render the graph is greater then the sleep time, so the "animation" doesn't work well.

Is there a way to make `GraphStream` only render the objects that changed (only 2 node in this case)?