# Translate MouseEvent coordinates to GraphStream's element coordinates

Tags: java, coordinates, mouseevent, graphstream

***tl;dr*** how to get closest `GraphicElement` coordinates given `MouseEvent` coordinates?

I created a [big graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72691014/make-graphstream-render-only-what-changed) that represents the road map of a certain region using `Graphstream` and I'm trying to find the closest node to an occuring `MouseEvent`.

My problem is that the `MouseEvent` coordinates are relative to the frame resulotion while my `GraphicElement`'s coordinates are longitude and latitude of real location.

For example, when clicking on a Node and get it using `MouseManager` with the following code:

```java
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        super.mouseReleased(e);
        GraphicElement graphicElement = view.findNodeOrSpriteAt(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if(graphicElement!= null){
            System.out.println( "node "+graphicElement.getLabel()+ ", xy ("+graphicElement.getX() +","+ graphicElement.getY()+").");
            System.out.println( "MouseEvent xy ("+e.getX() +","+e.getY()+").");
        }
    }
```

the output will be:

```
node 2, xy (34.7811627,32.0528169).
MouseEvent xy (281,489).
```

Is there a `GraphStream` built-in method or someother way I can translate the frame's coordinates to my coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of reading and debuging while trying to understand how `view.findNodeOrSpriteAt();` is working I've found a solution.

The [Camera](https://data.graphstream-project.org/api/gs-core/current/org/graphstream/ui/view/Camera.html) class *(view.getCamera( ))* have methods to do exactly what I was looking for.
`transformGuToPx(double x, double y, double z)` -> coordinates to pixels.
`transformPxToGu(double x, double y)` -> pixels to coordinates.

So, using them I can convert the `MouseEvent` coordinates:

```java
view.getCamera().transformPxToGu(mouseEvent.getX(), mouseEvent.getY());
```